# uWSGI - is it safe to set chmod-socket to 666?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I use Django with uWSGI and here is my django.ini file:

```
# django.ini file
[uwsgi]

# master
master                  = true
touch-reload =  /www/django.ini


# maximum number of processes
processes               = 8

# the socket (use the full path to be safe)
socket          = /tmp/uwsgi.sock


# with appropriate permissions - *may* be needed
chmod-socket    = 666

# the base directory
chdir           = /www/proj

# Django's wsgi file
wsgi-file          = /www/proj/proj/wsgi.py

# the virtualenv
home            = /home/me/.djenv

# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

Also I have

```
# ls -al /tmp/uwsgi.sock
srw-rw-rw- 1 me me 0 Mar 13 03:07 /tmp/uwsgi.sock
```

Where `me` is a user of `www-data` group

I am uneasy about `666` permission of `chmod-socket` however when I comment it out, and reinitate the script by `uwsgi --ini django.ini` I get `502 Bad Gateway`.

So wondering if giving the socket 666 permission can pose a security issue, and if so how to fix it?

Comment: Does `umask = 0660` work?

Comment: @dhke not sure what you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry, i meant `chmod-socket  = 660`. ...

Comment: @dhke 660 also yields 502 error.

Comment: Well, it seems you are not the first one with this particular problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431065/multiple-sites-uwsgi-django-and-security. Can you make sure, the webserver runs in the same group as the socket?